# Как написать парсер для Wavefront .obj на Си

Tags: c, парсер

Как написать парсер для Wavefront .obj на Си?

Я новичок в программирование на Си, нет опыта в написании парсера.
С чего начать?
Каков вообще принцип работы парсера?

Comment: А зачем? Для тренировки? Если надо для работы -- возьмите flex+bison

Comment: для тренировки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Формат Wavefront OBJ предназначен для
> хранения моделей трёхмерной графики. Я
> реализовал его возможности не
> полностью, а только то, что связано с
> представлением геометрии
> многогранников. В результате получился
> абстрактный класс PutWavefrontOBJ и
> функция loadOBJ для чтения файла:  ...
> А также класс GetWavefrontOBJ и
> функция saveOBJ для записи в файл: 
> ... Для того, чтобы записать данные
> объекта типа Polyhedron в файл и
> обратно предназначены следующие
> классы:  ...

[Формат Wavefront OBJ](http://prografix.narod.ru/rus_file_obj.html)

Answer (score 1):

Возьмите какую-нибудь библиотеку( в гугле они есть ) и с помощью них пишите парсер.

Вот [эту](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/) библиотеку посмотрите. Или [эту](http://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~ares.lagae/libobj/index.html). Или может быть [эту](http://code.google.com/p/saitoobjloader/)